# How to take TimeZone out of the Binding for DateTime in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing /Date(1337904300000)/ back in my model to be bound by the Default MVC 4 model binder.  By my calculation this should be 5/24/2012 8:04 PM but the model binder is making the DateTime variable that it is bound to {5/25/2012 12:05:00 AM}.  I am in the EST and it appears that it is taking the time I sent back and adding the 4 hour difference.  How can I set it up so it just takes the time as it was input and save it to the model as such?

Answer (score 1):

Handling timezone is a quite tricky stuff, and the way dotnet handles dates depends on a property of DateTimes called TimeKind that specifies if the date is expressed in local time or in absolute time. Needless to say most of datasourced set this enumeration to *Unknown*...so various component of the systen make different assumptions...causing the knind of problems you experienced. The firts thing to do is to set thie TimeKind before sending any datetime to the client side. Unluckly this is not the only problem...there are others. Please refer to this post of my blog, where you can find an in deep analysis of all TimeZone related problems: 
[Asp.net Mvc and the Nightmare of Dates and Time Zones](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2012/09/10/Aspnet-Mvc-and-the-Nightmare-of-Dates-and-Time-Zones.aspx)